# Symfony2 authentication method in the same firewall

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I'm new to Symfony2. I read documentation and saw some config for login form
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
```

I dont understand why there are 2 security methods http_basic and form_login in the same firewall? Which method security system will use? http_basic or form_login or both? Is it redundant?
Some questions above seem stupid but It seems symfony2 security component documentation so poor.

Answer (score 3):

In old `Symfony` documentation there was a small tip:

> When the user is not authenticated and if there is more than one
>   authentication mechanisms, Symfony2 automatically defines a default
>   entry point (in the example above, the login form; but if the user
>   send an Authorization HTTP header with wrong credentials, Symfony2
>   will use the HTTP basic entry point).

But in next versions when documentation were reorganized it was reduced and I don't know why.

So I opened a [new issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5004) in `symfony-docs` repository on `GitHub` with the proposal to restore the tip.

The quote from [@WouterJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149495/wouter-j)'s answer:

> The code seems to no longer work as described in the
>   quoted paragraph. It seems to always use form login, except when there
>   is no Authentication header sent and the HTTP basic credentials are
>   correct.

So you were right — it's not trivial at all. Just follow the issue if you want to know the conclusion.

Comment: I know http_basic and form_login but I'm confused by the config in cookbook. Why there are 2 security methods in the same firewall? http_basic is redundant if we have form_login?

Comment: @Geany: You were right — it's not trivial to find the answer. I'm going to post an issue to `Symfony` documentation.

Comment: Okay thank you @Andrey. Now I want to dig into security component to build a custom authentication but it seems security component and bundle very few information and hard to understand.

Comment: @Geany: Added more information based on the answers to the issue